# I can't setup Python

Tags: python

My computer Windows 7 (64-bit)...One or more issues caused the setup to fail. Please fix the issues and then retry setup. For more inforation see the log file. At least Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 are required to install Python 3.10.1 (64-bit)

Comment: Python 3.9 and higher requires windows 10 or higher
[link](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

Comment: Try to search 'python' in the microsoft store and download, good luck

Comment: Windows 7 is not supported anymore. Your options are: 1) Update to a newer version of windows 2) change to some other OS 3) Stick with outdated, potentially vulnerable software and be on your own.

Comment: You might have to settle for 2 or at least lower versions of 3. I know that the RPi 2 can handle it, so a W7 64bit should.

Answer (score 2):

> At least Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 are required to install Python 3.10.1 (64-bit)

You are running Windows 7, you need Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 or higher to run Python 3.10.1.

You can:

1. Install a newer operating system like Windows 10/11.
2. Install an earlier Python version, I would recommend version 3.8 as that is the latest version that can run on Windows 7 according to the [Windows download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).